# IPC-Bridge: Matlab Invalid MEX-file error

Tags: ros, matlab

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I installed IPC successfully (i think), but when i try to run the Publisher/Subscriber examples i get the "Invalid MEX-file" error:

Invalid MEX-file
'/opt/ros/diamondback/stacks/ipc_bridge_stack/ipc_geometry_msgs/bin/geometry_msgs_Twist.mexglx':
libipc.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Error in example_subscriber (line 13)
pid=geometry_msgs_Twist('connect','subscriber','example_module','twist');

I don't understand what's wrong, can you help me out?
Thanks in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/48127/ipc-bridge:-matlab-invalid-mex-file-error/) by [nvoltex](https://answers.ros.org/users/3575/nvoltex/) on ROS Answers with karma: 131 on 2012-11-12

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Here's the solution for your problem

http://cutler.mit.edu/manblog

Cheers!

---

Originally posted by [josemscnogueira](https://answers.ros.org/users/3383/josemscnogueira/) with karma: 56 on 2012-12-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ipso](https://answers.ros.org/users/2486/ipso/) on 2012-12-02**:
It is probably a good idea to copy the relevant parts of the posting you are referring to into your answer, as a blog is dynamic (as in: it changes over time). Your answer would serve as a 'permanent' copy, so the information is never lost.